# Ansible galaxy provisionner is not using private key in Vagrant

Tags: git, ansible, vagrant, ssh-keys, ansible-galaxy

I have the following vagrantfile

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|

  config.ssh.insert_key = true
  config.vm.define "dev" do |app|
    app.vm.provider "docker" do |d|
      d.image = "allansimon/allan-docker-dev-python"
      d.has_ssh = true
    end

    app.ssh.username = "vagrant"

    app.vm.provision "file", source: "~/.ssh/id_rsa", destination: ".ssh/id_rsa"


    app.vm.provision "permits-root-to-clone", type: "shell" do |s|
      s.inline = "cp /home/vagrant/.ssh/id_rsa /root/.ssh/id_rsa"
    end
    # if i put here a new shell provisionner , to the exact same repo than in my galaxy roles , it works

    app.vm.provision "ansible_local" do |ansible|
      ansible.galaxy_role_file = "build_scripts/ansible/requirements.yml"
      ansible.playbook = "build_scripts/ansible/bootstrap.yml"
    end
  end
end
```

The `requirements.yml` reference some private ansible roles, that are git-cloned

like this

```
- src: git@gitlab.mydomain.com:ansible-roles/myrole.git
  scm: git
  version: 'master'
  name: myrole
```

I'm injecting my desktop private key inside the vagrant

- it works in the sell provisionner
- it works if after I `vagrant ssh` inside the machine

but it does not work with the ansible_local provisionner
with the error

```
==> dev: Running provisioner: ansible_local...
    dev: Running ansible-galaxy...
 [WARNING]: - supervisord was NOT installed successfully: - command git clone
git@gitlab.mydomain.com:ansible-roles/myrole.git myrole failed in
directory /tmp/tmpQNgCTo (rc=128)
ERROR! - you can use --ignore-errors to skip failed roles and finish processing the list.
Ansible failed to complete successfully. Any error output should be
visible above. Please fix these errors and try again.
```

Is there a way to force ansible in vagrant to use a specific private key ?

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is because ssh client is either not able to locate your private key or unable to use it (permission issue?) inside the vagrant box to use to authenticate against the git repository. You should perhaps add a default config file (`~/.ssh/config`).

It seems to be confirmed because when you had connected using ssh to the vagrant box, the local ssh client is able to get the key using the `ssh-agent` which is forwarded alongside the connection from your desktop machine.

If you want to debug manually

- ssh in the vagrant box
- kill the ssh-agent (`ssh-agent -k`)
- retrieve the git repository manually (`git clone git@gitlab.mydomain.com:ansible-roles/myrole.git`) or try to ssh directly (`ssh git@gitlab.mydomain.com`) that could help
- spot the error